# Only matching GET and POST routes if a static file doesn't match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this route:
`app.get('/:a/:b/:c', routes.get);`

And this static definition:

```
app.use('/test', express.static(__dirname + '/test'));
```

Now, the problem arises when I try to access `/test/a/b.js`. Since it matches both paths, `routes.get` is triggered. How do I prevent this, and only route if a static resource file wouldn't be served otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/test'))` before `app.use(app.router)`.

Middleware runs in the order defined in `.configure()`.